# How do I display a text output when I click deselect all?

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

For my shiny app, I am using a pickerInput. When "deselect all" is selected, the output of my datatable shows an error. I am looking to print a string that says " Make sure to select an option!" when deselect all is selected. Do I have to use observeEvent, or can I use an if statement in my server code?

Here is an example of the pickerInput code:
`pickerInput("type", "Select Option", choices = c("a","b","c", "d"), selected = c("a","b","c","d"), options = list('actions-box' = TRUE), multiple = T)`

Here is an example of the server code:
 `output$one<- DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(caption = "table", options = list(pageLength = 50),tab1<- rbind(red, blue,green, yellow)%>% filter(num> .450, letter == input$type))`

Comment: Try looking at validate: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.7.1/topics/validate

Comment: Please provide a minimal *reproducible* example.

Comment: @Limey In my pickerInput, when I click "Deselect All", the output area where My DT::datatable usually is says "Error[Error]". Instead, when I click "Deselect All", I want it to say "Choose an option".

Answer (score 0):

If error you can hide the datatable or return NULL and display a message via shinyalert.